# Navigating without the navigation prop - typescript typings

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I'm trying to include React Navigation 6.x into a React Native project with Redux and therefore need to be able to access the navigator from outside components.

I'm following this guide ([Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)) and have essentially the same code as in their example, which functionally works fine:

```js
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}
```

However I'm also using Typescript.

React Navigation also have a guide on integrating Typescript ([Type checking with TypeScript](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript)) which shows how to type the navigation ref itself, which works also fine:

```
export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef<RootStackParamList>();
```

There is no example for typing the `navigate` function though, and I haven't been able to get anything to work.

I thought the solution would be to copy the typing for the `navigationRef.navigate()` method ([defined here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/2f8cbfcc593d92080b73f9cd5d31f4d1ab22b768/packages/core/src/types.tsx#L190)) and simply apply it to the wrapper function:

```
// navigationRef.navigate() typing...
//
// navigate<RouteName extends keyof ParamList>(
//   ...args: undefined extends ParamList[RouteName]
//     ? [screen: RouteName] | [screen: RouteName, params: ParamList[RouteName]]
//     : [screen: RouteName, params: ParamList[RouteName]]
// ): void;


type ParamList = RootStackParamList;
type Navigate = <RouteName extends keyof ParamList>(
  ...args: undefined extends ParamList[RouteName]
    ? [screen: RouteName] | [screen: RouteName, params: ParamList[RouteName]]
    : [screen: RouteName, params: ParamList[RouteName]]
) => void;

export const navigate: Navigate = (name, params) => {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}

// or...

export const navigate: typeof navigationRef.navigate = (name, params) => {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}
```

That unfortunately gives the following error:

```
Argument of type '[(undefined extends RootStackParamList[RouteName] ? [screen: RouteName] | [screen: RouteName, params: RootStackParamList[RouteName]] : [screen: ...])[0], (undefined extends RootStackParamList[RouteName] ? [screen: ...] | [screen: ...] : [screen: ...])[1]]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined extends RootStackParamList[(undefined extends RootStackParamList[RouteName] ? [screen: RouteName] | [screen: RouteName, params: RootStackParamList[RouteName]] : [screen: ...])[0]] ? [screen: ...] | [screen: ...] : [screen: ...]'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `navigationRef.navigate(name, params)`, you can try with this

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

export function navigateTo(routeName: string, params?: object) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate(routeName, params));
  }
}
```

this works for me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
export const navigate = (name: keyof RootStackParamList) => {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name)
  }
}
```

even better:

```
export const navigate = (
  name: keyof RootStackParamList,
  params?: StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>['route']['params']
) => {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params)
  }
}
```

Comment: how to import StackScreenProps?

Comment: `import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack'`

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the type of `navigationRef.navigate`

```
export const navigate: typeof navigationRef.navigate = (name, params) => {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's definitely more succinct, but I get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: If you get the same error then your annotation for `createNavigationContainerRef` isn't correct. You need to share the type of `RootStackParamList` as well as the code you're using to call `navigate`

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what `RootStackParamList` is. It can simply be `interface RootStackParamList { Home: undefined }`. I'm not calling it anywhere yet but that wouldn't really be relevant anyway.

Comment: Any luck on it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
export const navigate: typeof navigationRef.navigate = (name, params?) => {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
};
```